# Audio is blocked for 'autoplay' after clicking play?

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm building a Vue app that plays music.  Here is the relevant HTML

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <button type="button" ref="play" class="btn btn-primary">
      <font-awesome-icon id="playIcon" icon="play" />
      </button>
      <audio ref="audio"></audio>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here is the method to play music.  The source of the audio is correctly set in an earlier function.

```
togglePlay(update) {
      if (this.isLoaded != true) {
        return;
      }

      if (this.isPlaying == true) {
          this.audioDOM.pause();
          this.isPlaying = false;
          if (update) {
            this.sendUpdate();
          }
      } else {
          this.audioDOM.play();
          this.isPlaying = true;
          if (update) {
            this.sendUpdate();
          }
      }
    }
```

In the `mounted()` portion of the Vue component, I have this:

```
this.playBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.togglePlay(true);
    }, false);
```

However, it does not start the audio because it throws an autoplay error when it reaches the line `this.audioDOM.play()` and says I need to prompt the user for input.  However, clearly the user is providing input, by clicking the play button! What do I need to change?

Comment: this also happens if I change the button to use `@click="togglePlay(true)"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event to this.togglePlay. The event has to exist in the context of the calling function otherwise it won't know that it was triggered by the user.

Try this

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <button
          type="button"
          @click="togglePlay($event)" <!-- here I have added @click as an event handler -->
          class="btn btn-primary"
      >
      <font-awesome-icon id="playIcon" icon="play" />
      </button>
      <audio ref="audio"></audio>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
methods :{
    togglePlay(ev) { //since update is always true we don't need it,
      if (this.isLoaded != true) { // lets get the event instead
        return;
      }

      if (this.isPlaying == true) {
          this.audioDOM.pause();
          this.isPlaying = false;
          this.sendUpdate();
      } else {
          this.audioDOM.play();
          this.isPlaying = true;
          this.sendUpdate()
      }
    }

  }
}

<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Awkward. Turns out the error was a `DOMException` because I had set the source wrong.  Whoops!